# Running Enterprise Search as a service

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic's [Enterprise Search Installation Guide](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/enterprise-search) goes as far as starting the process locally - which is obviously not very stable.

When installed from a `.deb` or `.rpm`, a service is actually set up and ready to use but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working!?

When I start the service, all I can see is:

```
$ systemctl status enterprise-search

● enterprise-search.service - Elastic Enterprise Search
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/enterprise-search.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-07-10 15:26:17 UTC; 3s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/index.html
   Main PID: 9144 (java)
      Tasks: 19 (limit: 9536)
     Memory: 209.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/enterprise-search.service
             └─9144 java -cp /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/lib/jruby-stdlib-9.2.13.0.jar:/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/lib/jruby-core-9.2.13.0-complete.jar -Djruby.cli.warning.level=NIL -Djava.a>

Jul 10 15:26:17 ip-172-31 systemd[1]: Started Elastic Enterprise Search.
Jul 10 15:26:17 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[9144]: Found java executable in PATH
Jul 10 15:26:18 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[9144]: Java version detected: 11.0.11 (major version: 11)
Jul 10 15:26:18 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[9144]: Enterprise Search is starting...
Jul 10 15:26:18 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[9144]: Logs can be found in the location configured via the 'log_directory' setting (typically /var/log/enterprise-search)
```

But the logs don't have any new entries and nothing's listening on the defined port. Whereas starting the search just as a normal process as

```
sudo /usr/share/enterprise-search/bin/enterprise-search
```

Works perfectly fine.

`nohup` is also not helpful, the process stops very shortly after it starts, exactly as seen in [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-keep-enterprisesearch-running-all-the-time/274448/10)

I have added a [comment](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-keep-enterprisesearch-running-all-the-time/274448/15) to that thread but as it was already marked as solved I don't expect to see an answer. The solution provided did not work for me.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

`journalctl -u enterprise-search.service` reveals that the service is currently failing due to permission issues to its own log.

e.g.

```
Jul 11 16:57:53 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[284346]: Unexpected exception while running Enterprise Search:
Jul 11 16:57:53 ip-172-31 enterprise-search[284346]: Error: Permission denied - /var/log/enterprise-search/stats.log at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1237:in `sysopen'
```

Changing the owner to `enterprise-search` for the following:

```
app-server.log
connectors.log
filebeat
stats.log
system.log
worker.log
```

resolves the issue temporarily but it will resourface when the logs get rotated.

The initialisation now fails with:

```
enterprise-search[286929]: Unexpected exception while running Enterprise Search:
enterprise-search[286929]: NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
enterprise-search[286929]:     run! at /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/shared_togo/lib/shared_togo/cli.class:115
enterprise-search[286929]:   <main> at bin/enterprise-search-internal:15
systemd[1]: enterprise-search.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: enterprise-search.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm guessing this will still be related to privileges but I'm a bit stuck as to what else I have to change. I also have no clue how to make sure that the logs stay with the `enterprise-search` user on rotation.

Comment: `Active: active (running) ` so this service should be up and running

Comment: It should. But it isn't.

Comment: /var/log/enterprise-search is empty? Or is a reason why you hide the logs? did you tried `/etc/init.d/elas... | tail -f /var/log/syslog` and can you please decide if you use redhead (RPM) or debian (deb) based system?

Comment: Yes, the logs are empty - the service doesn't start. Using `journalctl -u enterprise-search.service` reveals that the service can't start because it has no permissions for its own log.

Comment: why you not update your question with this relevant information ls?

Answer (score 1):

The final solution for this is in the update of the question: changing the owners of the log files to `enterprise-search` resolved the issue. The final error mentioned above was related to the `elasticsearch` process crashing as the `enterprise-search` was starting up. Rebooting the server solved all the issues and everything is working fine now. Logs are rotating also.